# How can I stop Jupyter notebook / plt.quiver from stacking arrows on top of each other when using it more than once?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am having a problem with the matplotlib.pyplot.quiver() command and I hope you may know what to do about it. I am trying to write a code that takes a 2D array as input and outputs a color and an arrow for each of the angles in the array.

This is the function I use for the colors:

```
def plot_map(arr_2D):
    Farben = colors.Normalize(vmin=-np.pi, vmax=np.pi)
    plt.imshow(arr_2D, cmap='hsv', norm=Farben)
    return
```

And this is for the arrows:

```
def plot_arrows(arr_2D):
    X = np.arange(2)
    Y = np.arange(2)
    U = np.cos(arr_2D[X][Y])
    V = np.sin(arr_2D[X][Y])
    plt.quiver(X,Y,U,V, units = 'x', headaxislength = 2, headlength = 1, pivot = 'mid', scale = 1.1)
    return
```

The result I want looks something like this:

example array 1:
[[-np.pi  -np.pi/2] [-np.pi 0]]

picture 1: [It's a 2x2 grid, with each box being a certain color and having an arrow in it that points in the right direction. -180° (the first angle) is dark red, -90° is green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pebJW.jpg)

The code works fine so far, the problem arises when I call the same function again for a different array.

example array 2:
[[-np.pi/2  -np.pi/2] [-np.pi 0]]

picture 2: [I changed the first angle here. The color of the first angle did change and is now green, as it should be. A new arrow with the new angle has been added in the box. The problem is that the first arrow is still there. This means that there are now two arrows in the box, one of which is wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oG90.jpg)

I tried to find a command that would delete the first picture before generating the second one. I was unable to find such a command, and I don't know what else to try, as I don't actually know what is causing the problem.

For the final program I will be writing, all of the arrows are constantly changing direction. With this problem where it just adds the new arrow but doesn't delete the old one, there are basically just black circles there in the end. How do I get it to delete the old arrow before adding the new one? It also doesn't do that with the colors, the colors work just fine, so I'm confused.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `plt.figure(); stuff(); plt.figure(); stuff(); plt.show()`

Comment: "Stuff()" doesn't seem to exist in jupyter notebook, it always gives me an error "Object 'stuff' not found".  Is it part of a library maybe?

Comment: `stuff` is a shortcut for the _stuff_ you want to do :-) See below for an example

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You use `figure` to have, oh well, a NEW figure, so that what you draw later is not superposed on what you had drawn sooner.